# Javascript Callbacks and Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, callback, leaflet, w3c-geolocation

I'm very new to Javascript and ran into a problem I can't resolve/understand myself.

Let's say that I made "UserMap" class with a "userPosition" property and want to get coordinates using Geolocation API.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getCoordinates);
```

Then in the callback function I get latitude and longitude:

```
var coords = { "lat" : position.coords.latitude, "lng" : position.coords.longitude };
```

My question is: how can I make this callback function report back to the UserMap instance, so the userPosition property can be updated? Obviously `this.userPosition = coords;` won't work here. Now I feel pretty much helpless dealing with callbacks. I hope I don't have to make a new object every time I get the updated coords from a user.

Here is the wrong code:

```
    function UserMap() {
        this.map = L.map('map', {"zoomControl" : false});
        this.userPosition = {};
        this.boundary = {};

        if (navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getCoordinates);
        }
        else{ alert("Geolocation is not supported by your browser.");
            return false;
        }
        this.map.on("click", function(e) {
            alert("Lat: " + e.latlng.lat + " Lng: " + e.latlng.lng);
        });
        this.display();
    }

    UserMap.prototype.getCoordinates = function(position) {
        var coords = { "lat" : position.coords.latitude, "lng" : position.coords.longitude};
        this.userPosition = coords; // I understand why this line won't work, but can't find a workaround solution
    }

    UserMap.prototype.display = function() {
        var lat = this.userPosition.lat;
        var lng = this.userPosition.lng;
        this.map.setView([lat, lng], 18);
        var tile = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            minZoom: '16',
        }).addTo(this.map);
        L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(this.map)
            .bindPopup('You are here!')
            .openPopup();
    }
```

Comment: You need to set `this.userPosition` inside your `this.getCoordinates = function(){/*in here*/}`. Please show entire code.

Comment: It won't put the value into property since it's a callback function. That's the whole point.

Comment: The problem is that you can't access something that hasn't been created. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is Asynchronous, meaning it won't set the values inside of its success function until it gets a result. Therefore, your method is being called before your property exists. Use AJAX.

Comment: You will run into a problem with AJAX, as far as returning a value, which `onreadystatechange` will return to the `XMLHttpRequest`. This makes implementing your desire potentially difficult. Lots to think about.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will probably rethink my design.

Comment: Yeah, I think you can create Object methods that reimplement `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` every time they are called. But those methods won't be able to return values and Object properties are pretty much out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the callback you can use an ajax call, wich will interact with the server in a nonblocking manner.

If you use jquery you can do something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   data: coords
})
.done(function() {
  alert("done")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the map.locate function and the locationfound event to accomplish this:
Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tuchi35/3fTL7/1/ and also check the locate doc: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate

Basically, I removed your getCoordinates function and replace it with a call to the locate function and a event handler for the "locationfound" event:

`map.locate({setView:true}); 
    map.on('locationfound', function (data){
    L.marker(map.getCenter).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup('You are here!')
            .openPopup();
            });`

Hope it helps